# Build Xcode 13.2 App on iOS 15.4

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, xcode

I use my 2013 MacBook Air for occasional coding in Xcode. Now after returning to it after a while I wanted to build an App I wrote on my new iPhone on iOS 15.4.
However my MacBook fell out of the supported devices with the latest MacOS (12). Can I somehow still build the App on my phone with the newest version of Xcode I can get on my Mac? (Xcode 13.2.1 on MacOS 11.6)
Or is there any other way around this? I don't really want to buy a new Mac since the old one still works fine for my purposes and still runs extremely well. Building Apps until the newest release has been no problem.
Best Regards

Comment: Basically no. You need a modern xcode on a mac. You can rent macs in the cloud. Similarly github actions.

Comment: Except that you can't update to the latest version of Xcode your currently installed version should continue to work so you can build apps.